# Centering image (logo)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is the image that im trying to center, ive tryed different ways to          do this but to no success i think its to do with bootstrap pre determining the position and if so i dont know how to disable it can anyone help me with this issue many thanks.

```
      <div class="container">
             <div class="row">
                 <div class="col-md-5">
        <!--      <img src="../images/4uSupportLogo.png" class="" height="250px"/> -->
                   <br> </br>  
               <!-- <img src="../images/4uSupportLogo.png" alt="Logo" align="top" width="300" height="200"  </br> -->
                      <!--   <img src="../images/4uSupportLogo.png" width="300" height="200" style="display:block; margin-left:auto;
 margin-right: auto;" align="center" /> -->
                 <center>  <img src="../images/4uSupportLogo.png" class="img-responsive" width="300" height="200"> </center>


               <br> </br>  

         </div>
       </div>
     </div>


     <div class="container">
         <div class="row">
             <div class=" col-md-12 well text-center">
                 <h4><i><strong>The Username or Password is incorrect please try again.</strong></i></h4>
               <p>
                   If you have forgot your password and would like to reset it please contact Jack </p>

               <input type="button" 
                      value="Request New Password" 
                      onclick="location='../forgot_password/forgot.php'" />




               </div>

             </div>
         </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that the row is just positioning the image wrongly.. `<center><img></center>` should work fine.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Image</h2>
  <p>The .img-responsive class makes the image scale nicely to the parent element (resize the browser window to see the effect):</p>                  
  <center><img src="https://media.giphy.com/media/l0HlSYVgZLQ1Y4GdO/giphy.gif" class="img-responsive" alt="Cinque Terre" width="304" height="236"></center><br><br>
<img src="https://media.giphy.com/media/l0HlSYVgZLQ1Y4GdO/giphy.gif" class="img-responsive" alt="Cinque Terre" width="304" height="236">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

[Source](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_css_images.asp)

Comment: The `<center>` tag has been deprecated, I wouldn't recommend using it.

Comment: Thanks for your help i appreciate it :D

Comment: @PaulRedmond that wasn't part of the question and i think that i showed the solution and the error that led to it pretty well with using `center` but thanks that you mentioned that..
@UnicornLauncher it was an honor as this was also my first answer to any question ever on this website xD

Answer (score 1):

The `img-responsive` isn't doing anything to fix it left. Content flows left to right normally, so it's positioned normally. You can center it by adding `text-align: center;` on its parent element or by adding some rules directly to the image. This is better done on a class, but here's an example:

```
img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

http://codepen.io/paulcredmond/pen/RGOKwr

Comment: Thanks for your help i appreciate it :D